# Image manipulation in NodeJS with base64 image data

Tags: node.js, base64, image-manipulation

I have a nodejs server that receives images encoded in base64 through a websocket. I would like to do some image manipulation on those images and send them back. I searched a little bit on the net to find some library to help me doing this, but all I could find were libraries that take images stored somewhere in the server side, do the manipulation and save back the image. Apparently all of them take as input a string containing the filename of the image, so I guess under the hood they are fetching the image manually through a file stream.

My question is, is there a library that may help me working directly on base64 data (that is, passing the data as input to the functions) or should I save every time the image on the server, modify it and send it back? I would rather not go with the latter because I'm working on some high-performance application, and all this saving/loading looks a waste of cycles. Otherwise, do you see some other way I could achieve this (that is, getting the image file without saving and loading it back, for example)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Work with `Buffer`s.

```
var img = new Buffer(img_string, 'base64');
// Work with your images like other tutorials do.
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is going to work, the libraries apparently expect a filename as input to their functions, thus I guess they are opening a filestream and going to fetch manually the image. I will give this a try anyhow. Thanks!

Comment: @Masiar the libraries have to work with Buffers behind the scenes. They might need a filepath to open the file as a Buffer, but it all goes down to Buffers :-)

Comment: I definitely agree :)! But the API is clear about what kind of input is expecting. I'm going to try in a moment if the input source can be a buffer aswell. If that's the case, then you made my day. Otherwise nice try. I'll let you know asap.

Comment: Not working with the ImageMagick build for Node.js :(. `Caught exception: Error: Command failed: convert: no decode delegate for this image format '/tmp/magick-XXMs9mAu' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.
convert: missing an image filename 'jpg:-' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2970.` , it apparently needs an image.

Answer (score 0):

This one can work with "readable streams": https://github.com/aheckmann/gm

See the second set of examples in the readme.

Comment: Looks good. The problem is that I can't create a ReadableStream from a base64 format. I could convert in in a Buffer as @Florian did, but the only format accepted is ReadableStream.